# Which one is faster for object detection?

Tags: python, c++, object-detection

I want to do object detection. Right now I am using Python `tensorflow faster-rcnn` for object detection and `opencv` for image processing. In this situation I am taking 11 FPS. Should I pass to C++ to increase FPS? What is your idea? (Windows 10, RTX 2080 Ti, i9)

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: You might look into Pytorch

Comment: @RichardCritten next time i will do it. I am new sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a fast (real time) object detection method which performs as well as **Faster R-CNN** you can use [YOLO](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet). This one is written in **C** and is easy to use. In case of FPS, it depends on the image size as well as hardware configurations. But YOLO should perform much faster than RCNN.